# What do I need to be able to delete a user's workspace?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I need to delete the workspace of a user that has some files checked out.

My account is a member of `Administration Console users`, `TFS_APPTIER_SERVICE_WPG` and the `Application Tier`'s `Team Foundation Administrators` group.

The `Team Foundation Administrators` group has all privileges except "`Make requests on behalf of others`":

```
Administer Warehouse
Create Team Project Collection
Delete Team Project Collection
Edit Instance-level information
```

<strike>Make requests on behalf of others</strike>

```
Trigger events
Use full Web Access features
View instance-level information
```

I can access the `Team Foundation Server Administration Console`, but the `File` menu only has "`Exit`".

I understand that I can also do this from the `tf` utility, but I can't find it or perhaps I don't have this utility installed (Where can I look for it?).

Answer (score 0):

You need Team Explorer to be installed to get access to the te.exe utility.

Install it on your local computer and not the TFS server. It is a client utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the tf.exe from the command line.
The options you need are

- tf workspace allows you to see which workspaces exist for a certain
  user
- tf undo allows you to remove the locks tf delete ca delete
- tf delete can delete workspaces

using tf undo can be a lot of work but there are tools like [Team Foundation Server Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) that save time.

A good overview can be found at http://fci-h.blogspot.de/2011/01/how-to-force-undo-checkout-tfs.html